# MySQL - UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY MERGE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a nice way (without doing two queries and subjecting myself to race conditions which need to be dealt with, etc) to do a query like `UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY MERGE`

Say I have a table like this:

```
p_key    field1     field2     field3     field4
------------------------------------------------
1        1          1          4          burger
2        1          2          5          beer
```

`p_key` is the primary key and there is a unique index over `field 1, field 2`.

If I was then to run a query like:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET field2 = 1
WHERE p_key = 2
```

I would get a duplicate key error. I'd like to be able to write a query somewhat like

```
UPDATE `table`
SET field2 = 1
WHERE p_key = 2
ON DUPLICATE KEY MERGE
field3 = SUM(field3),
field4 = 'beer'
```

Which would result in the table now looking like:

```
p_key    field1     field2     field3     field4
------------------------------------------------
1        1          1          9          beer
```

Alternatively a `p_key` of `2` would also be acceptable (I don't mind which row gets deleted).

I hope that makes sense? I realise that there is no such thing as `ON DUPLICATE KEY MERGE` in MySQL, but how can I achieve this result in MySQL?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** In case it helps, here is is code for a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `p_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field4` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table` (`p_key`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 4, 'burger'),
(2, 1, 2, 5, 'beer');

ALTER TABLE `table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`p_key`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `field1` (`field1`,`field2`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
INSERT INTO table(p_key, field2)
    VALUES (2, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
        field3 = field3 + VALUES(field3),
        field4 = 'beer';
```

I should note that this assumes that `field3` has a default value of 0.  Otherwise, the value would always be `NULL`.  Or, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO table(p_key, field2)
    VALUES (2, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
        field3 = COALESCE(field3, 0) + VALUES(field3),
        field4 = 'beer';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY field3 = COALESCE(field3, 0) + VALUES(field3),' at line 4`. Is there such thing as an `UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`? I know there is an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: @LukeCousins . . . I was being oblivious.  `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is part of the `INSERT` statement, not the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: No worries :) Thanks for your help anyway. Currently I'm doing an `UPDATE` then catching the duplicate key error (if it happens) and then selecting the conflicting row, and issuing a delete and then update again having merged the differences myself.